# MPMoviePlayerController Won't Play Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, mpmovieplayer

The following MPMoviePlayerController will not present in my iOS application.

I am trying to make it appear when my tableView row is selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath  {

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl]];
[player setFullscreen:YES];
[player play];
[self.tableView addSubview:player.view];
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead try:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl]];
[player prepareToPlay];
[self presentViewController:player animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't add the view as a subview of a table view if I were you.
2. You have forgotten to give `player.view` a size.
3. You have forgotten to say `prepareToPlay` to the player. An MPMoviePlayerController absolutely will not play until you have done that.

Comment: Regarding 3., that is not entirely true. From the docs 'If a movie player is not already prepared to play when you call the play method, that method automatically calls this (prepareToPlay) method. However, to minimize playback delay, call this method before you call play.' https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MPMediaPlayback/prepareToPlay

Comment: @Jeff The _protocol_ docs may say that, but the actual implementation is up to _class_, and experience shows that for MPMoviePlayerController this behavior changed in iOS 6 and that calling `prepareToPlay` explicitly is now absolutely necessary. On the other hand, AVAudioPlayer (which implements the same protocol) behaves more the way the protocol docs seem to state.

Comment: I have an application using MPMoviePlayerController, and I do not have this issue. (Base SDK iOS 7.1). Could it be that this is resolved now?